# Update Null value

Tags: sql, sqlite

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345065/sql-query-replace-null-value-in-a-row-with-a-value-from-the-previous-known-value) reflects my issue. How to do this in SQLite?

I've tried `UPDATE` with self-joins, isolating the self join in sub-query, triggers, and something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/there-is-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement). Here is an example:

```
UPDATE stage 
SET title = 
(
  SELECT 
    prior.title
  FROM 
    stage prior,
    stage now
  WHERE 
    prior.rownum+1 = now.rownum
)
WHERE
title is null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every table in SQLite has got a pseudo-column called *rowid* (which can be accessible under several different names: `rowid`, `oid`, `_rowid_`, unless those names are assigned to other, real, columns). The rowid column is essentially a unique row identifier and you can use it as a sort criterion and/or in conditions.

The following query demonstrates how your problem can be solved with the help of *rowid*:

```
UPDATE stage
SET title = (
  SELECT title
  FROM stage AS prev
  WHERE title IS NOT NULL AND prev.rowid < stage.rowid
  ORDER BY prev.rowid DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
WHERE title IS NULL
```

Here's a [demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/76bd6/1).

You can read more about *rowid* in [this SQLite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Comment: Thank you Andriy. I tried your query on Fiddle, and yes it did work. But when I tried it on my db it did not. I tried it three ways: once in SQL Manager Firefox Add-in, once in Navicat (a commercial product), and once in the sqlite3 command line shell. None of them updated the table. Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas, sorry. My knowledge about SQLite is insufficient at the moment, and I would be happy to know the answer myself as well as to help you.

Comment: I didn't have any of the products you mentioned, but I have now installed the SQLite Manager Firefox add-on to see if I could do anything about my solution to make it work at least there. And guess what? I ran all the commands: created the table, inserted values, retrieved rows before the update, then updated the table using the exact same statement as in my answer and looked at the output of `SELECT *` again – and it worked. Since I am not a very experienced SQLite user, I can't really tell you what may have been the difference. The version of the add-on I've installed is 0.7.7, Firefox 12.0.

Answer (score 2):

I presented a solution for the problem you referred (I successfully tested on SQL2008, SQLite3 and Oracle11g). I copied that solution below:

```
CREATE TABLE test(mysequence INT, mynumber INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3, 5);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4, NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(5, NULL);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(6, 2);
SELECT t1.mysequence, t1.mynumber AS ORIGINAL
, (
    SELECT t2.mynumber
    FROM test t2
    WHERE t2.mysequence = (
        SELECT MAX(t3.mysequence)
        FROM test t3
        WHERE t3.mysequence <= t1.mysequence
        AND mynumber IS NOT NULL
       )
) AS CALCULATED
FROM test t1;

-- below here it was only tested in SQLite3, but I believe it should
-- work on other DBMS since it uses standard/non-proprietary SQL
UPDATE test
SET mynumber = (
    SELECT t2.mynumber
    FROM test t2
    WHERE t2.mysequence = (
        SELECT MAX(t3.mysequence)
        FROM test t3
        WHERE t3.mysequence <= test.mysequence
        AND mynumber IS NOT NULL
       )
);
```

Comment: Thanks G. How would that translate into an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Very nice G. Very elegant, I already checked an answer.. but this one worked flawlessly also. I wish I could pick two answers!

Comment: But mine uses only standard SQL! :) Now serious: there's no problem using proprietary SQL extensions, but this might be a concern if you plan migrating database provider in the future.