# How to keep track changing items in a stock portfolio?

Tags: database, algorithm, finance, financial

I have a system where people can pick some stocks and it values their portfolios but I'm having trouble doing this in a efficient way on a daily basis because I'm creating entries for days that don't have any changes(think of it like I'm measuring the values and having version control so I can track changes to the way the portfolio is designed).

Here's a example(each day's portfolio with stock name and weight):

```
Day1:
ibm = 10%
microsoft = 50%
google = 40%

day5:
ibm = 20%
microsoft = 20%
google = 40%
cisco = 20%
```

I can measure the value of the portfolio on day1 and understand I need to measure it again on day5(when it changed) but how do I measure day2-4 without recreating day1's entry in the database?

My approach right now(which I don't like) is to create a temp entry in my database for when someone changes the portfolio and then at the end of the day when I calculate the values if there is a temp entry I use that otherwise I create a new entry(for day2-4) using the last days data.  The issue is as data often doesn't change I'm creating entries that are basically duplicates.  The catch is: my stock data is all daily. I also thought of taking the portfolio and if it hasn't been updated in 3 days to find the returns of the last 3 days  for each stock but I wasn't sure if there was a better solution.

Any ideas? I think this is a straight forward problem but I just can't see a efficient way of doing it.

note: in finance terms, its called creating a NAV and most firms do it the inefficient way I'm doing it but its because the process was created like 50 years ago and hasn't changed. I think this problem is very similar to version control but I can't seem to make a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In storage terms is makes most sense to just store:

UserId - StockId1 - 23% - 2012-06-25
UserId - StockId2 - 11% - 2012-06-26
UserId - StockId1 - 20% - 2012-06-30

So you see that stock 1 went down at 30th. Now if you want to know the StockId1 percentage at the 28th you just select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stocks 
WHERE datecolumn<=DATE(2012-06-28) 
ORDER BY datecolumn DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

If it gives nothing back you did not have it, otherwise you get the last position back.

BTW. if you need for example a graph of stock 1 you could left join against a table full of dates. Then you can fill in the gaps easily.

Found this post here for example:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET number = (@n := COALESCE(number, @n))
ORDER BY date;
```

[SQL QUERY replace NULL value in a row with a value from the previous known value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345065/sql-query-replace-null-value-in-a-row-with-a-value-from-the-previous-known-value)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your approach.  Won't it be worst if I store the specific returns for each stock for everyday? or am I not understanding your approach?..by the way, in case it wasn't clear, in my example the percentage beside the stocks are the weight of how much I own..so on day 1 50% of my portfolio is microsoft, not microsoft went up 50% that day.