# Replacing Null value with previous

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-5

I am trying to change NULL values of a column in the database to its previous non-null value and save it in the database through a Linq|lambda query, have Entityframework 5.0 with MS-SQl server2012. example:

Time     Temperature
11:00    23
12:00    23
13:00    23
14:00    NULL
15:00    23
16:00    NULL
17:00    NULL
18:00    23
19:00    23

to

Time    Value
11:00    23
12:00    23
13:00    23
14:00    23
15:00    23
16:00    23
17:00    23
18:00    23
19:00    23

Exampe for SQL is here:
([SQL QUERY replace NULL value in a row with a value from the previous known value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345065/sql-query-replace-null-value-in-a-row-with-a-value-from-the-previous-known-value?rq=1))

Comment: I would suggest executing plain SQL query if you want to *update* data in database. Otherwise you need to load all data from table to client, update data in-memory and submit all changes back to database

Answer (score 0):

you try to do 2 things at the same time here.
- Fetch data
- Change data

I would split that up.
-First get the data where temperature == null
-then iterate over the results and set the values

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer correctly, but if you only get the data where temperature is NULL, you don't have enough data to figure out what to set the temperature to.