# mysql query to identify groups of data based on timestmp

Tags: mysql

I have records of smartmeter in an mysql database.

Records in timestamp order looking in generall as follow:

| key | timestamp | watt now |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 2022-10-04-01-01-01 | 10 |
| 000002 | 2022-10-04-01-02-01 | 10 |
| **000003** | **2022-10-04-01-03-01** | **101** |
| **000004** | **2022-10-04-01-04-01** | **101** |
| **000005** | **2022-10-04-01-05-01** | **102** |
| **000006** | **2022-10-04-01-06-01** | **101** |
| **000007** | **2022-10-04-01-07-01** | **102** |
| 000008 | 2022-10-04-01-08-01 | 10 |
| 000009 | 2022-10-04-01-09-01 | 10 |
| 000010 | 2022-10-04-01-09-01 | 10 |
| **000011** | **2022-10-04-01-09-01** | **107** |
| **000012** | **2022-10-04-01-09-01** | **101** |
| **000013** | **2022-10-04-01-09-01** | **109** |
| 000014 | 2022-10-04-01-09-01 | 10 |
| 000015 | 2022-10-04-01-09-01 | 10 |

I want to identify the groups with bigger number (lets say > 100)
and give them an incresing id. Also I want to get per group the first and last key id

Result of query should look like this:

| month | day | numbers of group | first id | last id | average watt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 04 | 0 | 000003 | 000007 | 102 |
| 10 | 04 | 1 | 000011 | 0000013 | 105 |

Any help apreciated

Comment: What defines as a group? From your example, it seems that consecutive keys with `>100` watt values will be one group, is that correct? Can you run `SELECT version();` to check your MySQL version and `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;` for the table structure and post them into your question?

Comment: Good question, a group is a number of values which :a) > 100 b) can be 1-x records, c) surrounded by lover values < 100. I marked 2 groups in the upper table with bold text. Hope that helps to get the idear

Comment: Ok, so how's my request for info on the second part in my comment above? The MySQL version and table structure please.

Comment: FanoFN the Table structure is like mention above,

Comment: CREATE TABLE iot.smartmeter (
 `key` INT auto_increment NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 watt varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
COMMENT='smart Meter log table';

Comment: There result of the query should looks like mention above

Comment: month day numbers of group first id last id average watt
10 04 0 000003 000007 102
10 04 1 000011 0000013 105

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something to identify them as a group. My first thought was using `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` but after multiple tries, I couldn't find a way. Then I thought about using `LAG()` but still I'm stuck at how to re-identify the rows as new group. After testing many times, I come up with this suggestion:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT s1.*,
         @n := COALESCE(IF(s1.skey=1,1,s2.skey), @n) As newGroup
   FROM smartmeter s1
  LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT skey,
       stimestamp,
       watt,
      LENGTH(watt) AS lenwatt,
       LAG(LENGTH(watt)) OVER (ORDER BY skey) llwatt
   FROM smartmeter) s2 ON s1.skey=s2.skey
  AND lenwatt != llwatt)
SELECT MONTH(stimestamp) AS Month,
       DAY(stimestamp) AS Day,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(skey)) AS 'numbers of group',
       MIN(skey) AS 'first id',
       MAX(skey) AS 'last id',
       AVG(watt) AS 'Average watt',
       CEIL(AVG(watt)) AS 'Average watt rounded',
       newGroup
   FROM cte
  WHERE watt >= 100
GROUP BY newGroup, MONTH(stimestamp), DAY(stimestamp)
```

By the way, I've changed some of your column names because `key` is actually a reserve word. Although you can use it as column name as long as you wrap it in backticks, I personally find it's a hassle to do it every time.

Ok, so my idea was to use `LENGTH(watt)` and `ORDER BY skey` in the `LAG()` function. Then I'll separate those rows where the length doesn't match and use that as a starting point for each new group. After that, I left join the result of that with `smartmeter` table. The next challenge is to assign each of the rows that doesn't match with previous `skey` value then I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1345260/10910692) and applied it into the cte.

Once those are done, I just write another query to fulfil your expected result. Although, some part of it is not exactly as what you expected.

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q4LOonYu)

Comment: FanoFN well noted and many thanks. I'll "transform" this to the real table, but what I understand so fahr that loocks great.  Will come back end of weekend. Thans again